# Dashboard.fireChange JavaScript error in pentaho CDE

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I'm using pentaho CE v7.1, the CDE Dashboard Creator.

I'm capturing a selection on a chart. When I try to set the selected category on a param, I do in the click action javascript:

```
Dashboards.fireChange('param_ordername', atom2.label);
```

where:

- param_ordername is the parameter
- atom2.label contains the string I want to set to the parameter

In the JavaScript console I can see this error when clicking:

> ReferenceError: Dashboards is not defined

I've tried this variant:

```
 this.dashboard.fireChange('param_ordername', atom2.label);
```

with the same results.

Any clue of how to set the value to the parameter?

Thanks,

Marta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your dashboard have requirejs support?

If so, the Dashboards object doesn’t exist anymore.

You have two options:

1. Disable requirejs support on the dashboard settings;
2. Change all references to Dashboards object to this.dashboard (note the spelling differences).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this.dashboard.fireChange() doesn't work,
but dashboard.fireChange() works for me with enabled requirejs support (Pentaho CE 7.1)

Answer (score 0):

With RequireJS, the usage would be:

```
this.dashboard.setParameter('param_name','param_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use
 `Dashboard.setParameter('parameterName','parameterValue')` or `Dashboard.setParametervalue('parameterName','parameterValue')`